# Strip CIDR notation from array

Tags: php

How can I strip the CIDR notations from all values in an array
For example I have an array of IP's ending in /32, I need to strip that off for each value in the array

Here is my code so far:

```
$ip_addresses = "1.1.1.1/32, 2.2.2.2/32, 3.3.3.3/32";
$ip_addresses_stripped_array = explode(",", $ip_addresses);
```

Comment: Will it always be ipv4 and a /32?

Comment: Yes, I want to strip everything off from the slash (/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `/32` is a constant substring, you can remove it and just explode on `,` (comma space):

```
$ip_addresses = "1.1.1.1/32, 2.2.2.2/32, 3.3.3.3/32";
$ip_addresses_stripped_array = explode(", ", str_replace('/32', '', $ip_addresses));

print_r($ip_addresses_stripped_array);
```

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.1.1.1
    [1] => 2.2.2.2
    [2] => 3.3.3.3
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split and remove with one operation.  This splits on comma space and `/32` and removes the empties:

```
$result = preg_split('#, |/32#', $ip_addresses, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.1.1.1
    [1] => 2.2.2.2
    [2] => 3.3.3.3
)
```